# Sort using argsort in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I try to sort an array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [5,3,7,2,6,34,46,344,545,32,5,22]
print "unsorted"
print arr

np.argsort(arr)

print "sorted"
print arr
```

But the output is:

```
unsorted
[5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 34, 46, 344, 545, 32, 5, 22]
sorted
[5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 34, 46, 344, 545, 32, 5, 22]
```

The array does not change at all

Comment: Such things are searchable in 1 minute in docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html 1. It returns indexes of sorted elements. 2. It doesn't do it in place, but returns new array.

Comment: Use `arr.sort()` for in-place sort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues here; one is that `np.argsort` returns an array of the *indices* which would sort the original array, the second is that it doesn't modify the original array, just gives you another.  This interactive session should help explain:

```
In [59]: arr = [5,3,7,2,6,34,46,344,545,32,5,22]

In [60]: np.argsort(arr)
Out[60]: array([ 3,  1,  0, 10,  4,  2, 11,  9,  5,  6,  7,  8])
```

Above, the `[3, 1, 0, ...]` means that item `3` in your original list should come first (the `2`), then item `2` should come (the `3`), then the first (index is `0`, item is `5`) and so on.  Note that `arr` is still unaffected:

```
In [61]: arr
Out[61]: [5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 34, 46, 344, 545, 32, 5, 22]
```

You might not need this array of indices, and would find it easier to just use `np.sort`:

```
In [62]: np.sort(arr)
Out[62]: array([  2,   3,   5,   5,   6,   7,  22,  32,  34,  46, 344, 545])
```

But this still leaves `arr` alone:

```
In [68]: arr
Out[68]: [5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 34, 46, 344, 545, 32, 5, 22]
```

If you want to do it in place (modify the original), use:

```
In [69]: arr.sort()

In [70]: arr
Out[70]: [2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 22, 32, 34, 46, 344, 545]
```

Comment: Just as a note, `np.sort(arr)` returns a copy of the sorted array rather than sorting in-place

Comment: @Josh, True, that's what `arr.sort()` is for, at the end, since `np.sort(arr)` leaves `arr` itself alone.

Answer (score 25):

`np.argsort` doesn't sort the list in place, it returns a list full of indicies that you are able to use to sort the list.

You must assign this returned list to a value:

```
new_arr = np.argsort(arr)
```

Then, to sort the list with such indices, you can do:

```
np.array(arr)[new_arr]
```

Comment: I think you mean `indices = np.argsort(arr); arr[indices]`. Note that `argsort` is not `sort`

Comment: @askewchan It's simply a name. OP can name it whatever he wishes :)

Comment: True, sorry, I meant your first sentence, "np.argsort doesn't sort the list in place, it returns a sorted list"  It returns the indices which would sort a list.  Look at what the OP example returns: `array([ 3,  1,  0, 10,  4,  2, 11,  9,  5,  6,  7,  8])`, which i would not call sorted.

Comment: @askewchan Thank you. I have never fully working with `numpy`, and so I will edit my answer

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
order = np.argsort(arr)
print np.array(arr)[order]
```

the [argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) response is the index of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your array sorted in-place you want `arr.sort()`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np  
In [2]: arr = [5,3,7,2,6,34,46,344,545,32,5,22]

In [4]: print arr
[5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 34, 46, 344, 545, 32, 5, 22]

In [5]: arr.sort()
In [7]: print arr
[2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 22, 32, 34, 46, 344, 545]
```